# replace ';' with ';\n'

Tags: sed

How can I replace `;` with `;\n` (semicolon followed by a newline) in sed?

I've tried building off of

```
sed s/;/\\n/g file
```

and

```
sed -e '/;/G' file
```

but I can't get either to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cheat a bit:  in `bash` you can say

```
sed $'s/;/;\\\n/g'
```

or, portably (POSIX):

```
sed "s/;/;$(printf '\\\n')/g"
```

`sed` does not portably/reliably handle backslash-escapes anywhere but in the pattern, and even there it's limited (POSIX only requires that `\n` be handled, not `\t` or the others).  Note that you also need a backslash before the `\n` so `sed` doesn't read it as the end of the command.

Comment: your second sed command is giving a `sed: -e expression... unterminated 's' command` when run in bash, first command works great tho, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ie 's/;/;\n/g' <file>
```

That's assuming you want to do it inline in the file, remove the "`i`" and just use "`-e`" if that's not the case.